# Android - Hosting in-app purchase content

Tags: android, hosting

I'm working on a proof of concept app (which will hopefully grow) where users can purchase packs of images using the in-app purchase options on Android.  My question is, where/how should the image packs being hosted?  Is there a standard method for doing this?  I've looked around and found nothing so far.  The packs will each be fairly large (10-50mb) so I can't just include everything in the initial download.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the digital content you have for purchase should be stored securely on a server which you host and control. Then when users purchase using your app (either directly from your website or via the Android Market with in-app billing), you then deliver the content after payment is made.

**EDIT:** I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box code but my preferred option is to have the app call a secure web service, posting credentials such as the payment reference, product purchased details and perhaps some secure details from your app which you can then validate on your server. Even if you're not going with Android in-app billing, they have an example and plenty of documentation which might help you devise your own solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I understand it needs to be hosted on a server, but I wasn't sure how it should be hosted there.  Is there an existing code base that already handles file requests and serving them back to an android device (so I don't have to reinvent the wheel)?  Or should I just host .zip files of each pack and download them from a direct url (not secure at all, so others could stumble across it).  Sorry for the confusion, and thanks again for your help!